# How to convert from an object of any type to string

Tags: c++

I have this problem, can someone help me?

```
boost::property_map<slGraph, edge_name_t>::type name1 = get(edge_name, graph);

slEdgeIterator ei, ei_end;
    for(tie(ei, ei_end) = edges(graph); ei != ei_end; ++ei){

        name1[*ei] = "UNKNOWN"; //(error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [8]' (or there is no acceptable conversion))

        }//end

slOutEdgeIterator outEdgeItr;
if(name1[*outEdgeItr].compare("UNKNOWN")==0)// (error C2039: 'compare' : is not a member of 'boost::detail::error_property_not_found')
{}
```

Comment: Check the docs on the objects you're using. (Bad answer for a bad question.)

Answer (score 0):

First error: Your type edge_name_t (whats the underlying type of edge_name_t?) must support an operator=(const char* str), which accepts a string as parameter. So if edge_name_t is a class just add and implement the operator and 
Second error: Same problem here. Whatever edge_name_t is, it doesn't offer a `compare`-method.
Anyway, you should insert the declaration of edge_name_t. Is it a string, your own class or what is it?

Btw. Since you didn't give much information, i can only assume, what you're trying to do, but i wouldn't use strings for this, since the comparison is relatively slow. If you don't want to name your edged but only to "flag" them, maybe it would be a better approach to use 'enums'.